# mysql : How to sort columns based on other columns

Tags: mysql, date, sorting, sql-order-by, sql-null

I am having a notifications table and want to sort by the read_at column as well as created_at column.

Notification Table

| id | read_at | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 21-jun-2021 12:56:12 |
| 2 | null | 22-jun-2021 13:12:43 |
| 3 | 24-jun-2021 19:43:42 | 23-jun-2021 16:34:45 |
| 4 | 23-jun-2021 17:00:03 | 23-jun-2021 16:40:22 |
| 5 | null | 24-jun-2021 11:41:32 |
| 6 | 24-jun-2021 21:12:12 | 24-jun-2021 19:45:22 |
| 7 | 25-jun-2021 03:14:08 | 25-jun-2021 03:12:57 |
| 8 | null | 25-jun-2021 09:59:22 |
| 9 | 25-jun-2021 12:41:40 | 25-jun-2021 12:41:09 |
| 10 | 26-jun-2021 01:59:59 | 25-jun-2021 20:09:02 |

All I wanted is something like this : \

```
sort (if read_at is null then read_at desc, created_at desc else created_at desc);
```

The resultant table should be :

| id | read_at | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 21-jun-2021 12:56:12 |
| 2 | null | 22-jun-2021 13:12:43 |
| 5 | null | 24-jun-2021 11:41:32 |
| 8 | null | 25-jun-2021 09:59:22 |
| 3 | 25-jun-2021 19:43:42 | 23-jun-2021 16:34:45 |
| 4 | 27-jun-2021 17:00:03 | 23-jun-2021 16:40:22 |
| 6 | 24-jun-2021 21:12:12 | 24-jun-2021 19:45:22 |
| 7 | 29-jun-2021 03:14:08 | 25-jun-2021 03:12:57 |
| 9 | 25-jun-2021 12:41:40 | 25-jun-2021 12:41:09 |
| 10 | 26-jun-2021 01:59:59 | 25-jun-2021 20:09:02 |

I am unable explain this very clear.

I want unread notifications at top sorted by created_at date.
If the notification are read, then the remaining should be sorted by created_at date.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by the boolean expression `read_at IS NULL` descending, which will return all rows with `read_at` that are `null` at the top and then by `created_at` descending (or ascending like your expected results):

```
ORDER BY read_at IS NULL DESC, created_at DESC -- or ASC ???
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should solve your problem.

Can't test it right now.

select id, read_at, created_at from notifications order by case when read_at is null then 1 else 0 end desc, created_at desc